# Script for assessing cross-coder reliability of segment length in R

Tags: r

I'm working on a project where I have multiple coders segmenting vocalizations from speakers in [ELAN](https://archive.mpi.nl/tla/elan). I want to assess cross-coder reliability - there is a function for this in ELAN but it doesn't appear to be flexible enough to do what I want so I'm hoping to create my own using R.

My first question is: is there a script that can already do this kind of task?

If not, I would like to do the following, using two example datasets to demonstrate:

```
 Coder1 <- tribble(~coder, ~segment_type, ~begin, ~end, ~dur, 
           "Coder1", "vocalization", 363,  364,  0.41,
           "Coder1", "vocalization", 356,  356,  0.33,
           "Coder1", "vocalization", 360,  360,  0.29,
           "Coder1", "vocalization", 369,  374,  4.92,
           "Coder1", "vocalization", 392,  392,  0.21)

 Coder2 <- tribble(~coder, ~segment_type, ~begin, ~end, ~dur, 
           "Coder2", "vocalization", 363,   364,   0.5,
           "Coder2", "vocalization", 369,   370,   0.83,
           "Coder2", "vocalization", 370,   371,   0.33,
           "Coder2", "vocalization", 371,   372,   0.505,
           "Coder2", "vocalization", 391,   392,   0.315)
```

- I want to create a column, `Coder1$Match`, that compares every row coded as "vocalization" in `Coder1$segment_type` with every row in `Coder2$segment_type` coded as "vocalization".
- If both `Coder2$begin` and `Coder2$end` are within 1s of `Coder1$begin` and `Coder1$end`, respectively, *and* `Coder2$Dur` is within 1s of `Coder1$Dur`, then `Coder1$Match` should be coded as TRUE, otherwise FALSE.

Expected output is as follows:

```
 > head(output)
 # A tibble: 5 x 6
   coder  segment_type begin   end   dur Match
   <chr>  <chr>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>
 1 Coder1 vocalization   363   364  0.41 TRUE 
 2 Coder1 vocalization   356   356  0.33 FALSE
 3 Coder1 vocalization   360   360  0.29 FALSE
 4 Coder1 vocalization   369   374  4.92 TRUE 
 5 Coder1 vocalization   392   392  0.21 FALSE
 >
```

Note that it shouldn't matter if, for example, Coder 2 has 2 segments that align with 1 segment coded by Coder 1 (both should be coded as TRUE in `Coder1$Match`) as I'd like to account for any instances where coders have captured the same vocalization segment but one may have coded it as two separate vocalizations and the other a single vocalization.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is close to what you are looking for?

We are using the `fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_full_join()` to check if a segment in `Coder1` is within a segment in `Coder2`. We repeat this step to check if a `Coder2` segment is within `Coder1`. Then we combine the results and filter out the rows where we didn't get a match. Finally, we apply the condition for `dur`.

```r
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(tidyverse)

fun_l1 <-
  list(\(x, y) x >= y - 1,
       \(x, y) x <= y + 1)
fun_l2 <-
  list(\(y, x) x >= y - 1,
       \(y, x) x <= y + 1)

cc_fun <- function(x, y, fun_l) {
  fuzzy_full_join(x,
                  y,
                  by = c("begin",
                         "end"),
                  match_fun = fun_l)
}

c1c2 <- cc_fun(Coder1, Coder2, fun_l1)
c2c1 <- cc_fun(Coder1, Coder2, fun_l2)

bind_rows(c1c2, c2c1) |>
  distinct() |>
  filter(!is.na(coder.x),!is.na(coder.y)) |>
  mutate(match = abs(dur.x - dur.y) <= 1) |> 
  select(-starts_with("segment_type"))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 9
#>   coder.x begin.x end.x dur.x coder.y begin.y end.y dur.y match
#>   <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>
#> 1 Coder1      363   364  0.41 Coder2      363   364 0.5   TRUE 
#> 2 Coder1      392   392  0.21 Coder2      391   392 0.315 TRUE 
#> 3 Coder1      369   374  4.92 Coder2      369   370 0.83  FALSE
#> 4 Coder1      369   374  4.92 Coder2      370   371 0.33  FALSE
#> 5 Coder1      369   374  4.92 Coder2      371   372 0.505 FALSE
```

Comment: Thank you! This looks great! I need to test it a bit but this is just what I was looking for - much appreciated!